# Error while using std::transform to print Map<string, vector<string*> >

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I am trying to overload the operator<< to print the vector of string* in MapType(see typedef below), but keep getting error. Please help. Here are the details, I have the following class:

```
typedef map<string, vector<string*> > MapType;
class Thesaurus{
public: 
     ...
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& ostrm, const Thesaurus& T);
private:
    MapType M;
    string DeRef(string* i);
    ...
};
```

Where

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& ostrm, const Thesaurus& T)
{
    for(MapType::const_iterator mItr = T.M.begin(); mItr!= T.M.end(); mItr++)
    {
        ostrm<< endl;   
        ostrm<< mItr->first<<"\t"; //print word
        transform(mItr->second.begin(), mItr->second.end(), ostrm, &Thesaurus::DeRef); // print synonyms vector
    }
    return ostrm;
}


string Thesaurus::DeRef(string* i)
{   
    return *i;
}
```

Use of transform in operator<< throws the following error:

```
"error C2248:'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios':cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'"
```

Comment: You're trying to pass a stream to transform. It expects an iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't use `std::transform` if you're not really transforming anything. Secondly, you're trying to pass an output stream reference as the third argument, but it should be an iterator. Thirdly, the `Thesaurus::DeRef` method is not static, so you can't pass it like that to any function. All of this should give you a lot more errors than the one in your question.

If you have a C++11 capable compiler, I would suggest something like this instead:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& ostrm, const Thesaurus& T)
{
    for (const auto& mapItem : T.M)
    {
        ostrm << '\n';
        ostrm << mapItem.first << '\t';

        for (const auto& strPtr : mapItem.second)
            ostrm << *strPtr;
    }

    return ostrm;
}
```

Instead of the inner loop, you *could* use [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) with [`std::ostream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator) like this instead:

```
std::transform(std::begin(mapItem.second), std::end(mapItem.second),
               std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(ostrm),
               [](const std::string* strPtr) { return *strPtr; });
```

Comment: I'm using C++98, could you please give some hint for the older version of C++.

Comment: @InnocentRetard Then make the `DeRef` function `static`, and use a variant of my call of `std::transform` but with your *static* function instead of the lambda.

Comment: That worked very well. Thank you. When the DeRef function was not static, at a different place in my code, I had to use this:     bind1st(mem_fun(&Thesaurus::DeRef),this). Now since DeRef is static, I can just use     &Thesaurus::DeRef! Thank you once again.